# Convert html entities for mobiles

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native, html-entities, mobile-development

I have an API which returns text which contains some HTML entities, e.g. `&nbsp;`. This is handled nicely on web and shown as space, but on mobile apps it's shown as text with value `&nbsp`. I use `React Native`, but I think the issue would also happen if I was coding in `Android` or `Ojbective-C`. What is the general approach for showing HTML entities on mobile apps, just like they are shown on the web?

I tried [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) in order to encode the strings and decode them afterwards. It worked for some examples, but for instance for `&nbsp` it didn't work.

Thanks :)

Comment: `he` handles `&nbsp;` perfectly fine.

Comment: @SLaks it seems I needed a confirmation it works for sure, so I would go look up for the bug elsewhere :D It works with mock data and finally I find the error in my data. Thanks for the comment :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake to expect [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) to work properly with uppercase version of the HTML entities. In the API I use there are some values which always come as upper case strings, so in my case the quickest solution was to convert them to lower case, apply the he.decode() function and then convert the value back to upper case. If I find a case where the strings have both upper and lower case letters, than it would be a more challenging task and will need another workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of packages which will allow the rendering of HTML in react-native. [This one for example](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview)

In general though, I would say this is a bad idea. Your API is heavily coupled to things that can only render HTML. A better idea would be to return plain text from the api and leave it up to the application to render it nicely.